# Define a web component inside another web component without polluting global namespace

Tags: javascript, web-component

Suppose I want to use a web component that use 10 web component internally, and if the component define it globally, Internals will pollute my global component namespace and I can't use their name for another components.

Is there any way to use a web component inside another web component without defining it via `customElements.define()`?

Comment: Having components with the same name that behave differently seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @Ouroborus they are like functions with same name or variables with same name, aren't they?

Comment: Yes, there is only one registry, so no 'internal components' and no duplicate names allowed. If you look at Youtube.com source they 'solve' the 'problem' with Element names like: ``<ytd-two-column-browse-results-renderer>`` Not elegant, maybe the future brings Shadow-DOM scoped elements.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman That is UGLY :( isn't there any proposal to add it in future?

Comment: This is not like an `iframe` Each component should have one purpose and one name. If you want to have different functionality then create another component. I would hate to find out that the `<input>` or `<video>` tags worked differently in different situations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some discussion around creating [scoped custom element registries](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/716) but nothing has a spec or been implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

[scoped custom element registry](https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/716) is not supported yet but you can use prefix name until the time it is supported for example if your component name is `x-foo` you can name your component `x-foo-title`, `x-foo-image`, etc.
for example in [jb-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jb-input) developer use sub web component like this:

```html
<jb-input>
    <jb-input-inbox-element slot="end-section">
        <div>after</div>
    </jb-input-inbox-element>
    <jb-input-inbox-element slot="start-section">
        <div>before</div>
    </jb-input-inbox-element>
</jb-input>
```